# getting an access token to sharepoint add-in

Tags: rest

I have a sharepoint site with list, and I want to get an access token for rest api calling, what url and maethods do I have to send in my post request?

Comment: There are multiple resources well published on the web ( Bing/Google "SharePoint REST" ).  If you have a specific problem you are trying to solve - please add more detail, and include what you have tried or what is not working.